# Creating table with checkmarks using buzztouch

Tags: ios, uitableview, buzztouch

I am creating an iOS app using BuzzTouch. I would like to create a table with checkmarks. When user click on any row, a checkmarks appears right to that row and by clicking again on the same row, it will disappear. The user can tick multiple rows and by leaving the view, the users choices will send to server.
Can someone please guide me or send a link to a tutorial how to build this.

Thanks.